# I am having trouble with basic installing packages and library calling

Tags: r, dplyr

When I execute

install.packages("dplyr")

I get

Error: invalid version specification ‘NA’
In addition: Warning message:
In utils:::packageDescription(packageName, fields = "Version") :
  no package 'knitr' was found

Then I call the library and it obviously doesn't work either -

library(dplyr)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pillar', details:
  call: utils::packageVersion("vctrs")
  error: package ‘vctrs’ not found
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.5.3

I am trying to use %>% and mutate.  Will not post that full code due to company policy.  I just need help  with why something as simple as installing packages and calling libraries doesn't work for me...

Comment: The error explains the problem. The package `knitr` was not found. `install.packages('knitr')`. Alternatively it is likely to be fixable just executing `install.packages("dplyr", dependencies = TRUE)` to install all dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
 install.packages('knitr', dependencies = TRUE)
```

?

Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: Error: invalid version specification ‘NA’
In addition: Warning message:
In utils:::packageDescription(packageName, fields = "Version") :
  no package 'knitr' was found

Comment: I got that error when running your code too - even though the whole package ran for a long time, it ended with that.

Comment: Are you using the most current version of R? If not, update both R and, if you're using it, R Studio. Then try to install again, and use a fresh session.

If that doesn't help: Instead of installing all dependencies at once via install.packages("knitr"), install them one by one, to see where the problem lies. To see which packages you need to install, use packageDescription("knitr")

Comment: Thanks, currently on hold with help desk to get admin to update.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to install vctrs and knitr first.  Then dplyr worked... I have know idea why this is so hard.  It's supposed to be the easy part...